# How do I preserve search results in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I searched the web for an answer to this but was not able to find it in official documentation, forum of IntelliJ or stackoverflow:

**In IntelliJ: (How) Can I have multiple search results kept open?**

I know there is the possibility of "Recent Find Usages" but this always does a new search. With a big code base this takes a lot of time. Or imagine you need to compare search results.

I now found a solution. See my answer...

Answer (score 5):

When opening the global search dialog (ctrl + shift + f) there is a gear-wheel icon in the lower left. There you can choose to "Open in new tab".
This will keep the previous search result window open and just create a new tab for the new search.

[image: screenshot]

This setting is at least active as long as IntelliJ stays open and also appies to all opened windows / instances of IntelliJ.

Found this answer in a discussion about Visual Studio Code feature request: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/16488
Thanks to github user jjinux (commented on 9 Mar 2017)